# Firefox Not Respecting Flex Shrink

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

**Goal:** A `nav`, using flexbox, where there's a logo to the left and a variable number of `nav` items to the right. When the `nav` items become wide enough where there's not enough room for both the `nav` and the logo, the logo shrinks.

```
.logo{
    display: flex; flex-shrink:1;flex-grow:0;
}
.nav-container{
    display: flex; flex-shrink:0;flex-grow:2;
}
```

**Problem:** It works great in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

Tried to use `flex-basis` but it created a specific ratio and broke the working example in Chrome.

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/leggomuhgreggo/pen/BobwYz

Thanks!

Comment: What is your version of firefox? Because it does work in my firefox

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to add `min-width:0` to your `.logo{}` rule. That allows it to shrink below its minimum intrinsic size (which Firefox computes as being the intrinsic width of the `img`).

[Here's your demo with that change](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaxxqR).

(Side note: The fact that Chrome and Firefox behave differently here is an instance of [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=823483).  Chrome is honoring the `img's` percent max-width when computing the minimum intrinsic size of the flex item; Firefox is not. If you drop the `max-width:100%` on the `img` style rules, then you'll see that Chrome changes its rendering to match Firefox & refuses to let the logo shrink, unless you add `min-width:0`.)

Comment: This helped when working with `input` containers within a `flexbox` thanks.